Apple account is using an old email address I no longer have access to. How do I change it?
I have 2 Apple ID accounts - one for personal use, and one for an app developer account.
I used to have 2 email accounts for each, but I lost one - the personal one - when I shut down my website.
I cannot use the email address associated with the developer account as it says there is already an Apple account associated with that email address.
Other than create a whole new Gmail account specifically for just my Apple ID, is there anything I can do?

Apple support excels at answering questions like this since they can access all of your data and understand their policies. What specifically can we help with that isn’t going to be clarified by reaching out to them for support?

Just a thought…why not create an alias in Gmail (or other email service) and associate it with your Apple ID?  It’s not clear from your question whether or not you have access to your Apple account.  Can you clarify with an [edit]?
